# Double more-than symbol in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What does this: >> mean in JavaScript?

Seen in this context:

```
document.onkeydown = document.onkeyup = function(e,v,y,k) {
  (i=e.keyCode-37)>>2 || (keys[i] = e.type[5]&&1||(0))
}
```

Comment: I would fire whoever wrote that line of code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Javascript Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

> Left shift    a << b  Shifts a in binary
>   representation b (< 32) bits to the
>   left, shifting in zeros from the
>   right.
>
> Sign-propagating right shift  a >>
>   b Shifts a in binary representation b
>   (< 32) bits to the right, discarding
>   bits shifted off.

Answer (score 25):

`>>` is the [bitwise right shift operator](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsoprrshift.htm).

For example: `4 >> 1` equals `2` because 4 is `100` in binary notation, which is shifted one bit to the right, giving us `10` = `2`

Comment: what is the significance by getting the binary notation conversion, in this context, and then using the bitwise right shift operator?

Comment: I don't see a reason for it. They could have written it as (i=e.keyCode-37)/4 instead, since right shifting two bits is essentially the same as dividing by four.

Answer (score 3):

```
(i=e.keyCode-37)>>2
```

This code is discarding the two least significant bits of i (similar to dividing by 4), and comparing the result to zero. This will be false when the key pressed is 37-40 (arrow keys), and true otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Bitwise shift operator (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)).

Now, as to exactly what it's doing here I'm not sure... I'm sure some of our larger-brained bretheren that actually finished college could help us out with that.  ;^)