# What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

### What is this?

This is a collection of questions that come up every now and then about syntax in JavaScript. This is also a Community Wiki, **so everyone is invited to participate in maintaining this list.**

### Why is this?

Stack Overflow does not allow searching for particular characters. As a consequence, many questions about operators and other syntax tokens are not found easily when searching for them. This also makes closing duplicates more difficult. The list below is to help with this issue.

The main idea is to have links to existing questions on Stack Overflow, so it's easier for us to reference them, not to copy over content from the ECMAScript Spec.

Additionally, this is a blatant copy of the [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) symbol reference. We needed a JS one.

---

**Please help. Edit and add links to other operators/syntax references, or if you can't find good questions/answers on a particular piece of syntax, add an answer to this question and link it**

Comment: @amnotiam: Doesn't really matter, but this may be much easier to find/remember than any of the individual posts this links to. I had *such* a hard time searching for info on the `|` operator. The [PHP version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) has been very useful as a go-to for closing dupes.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that this should, barring an official policy change, remain. ...or, perhaps, added to the tag-wiki. But the wiki doesn't seem an appropriate place for this content. It seems, despite the lack of potential for any 'answers' like enough a 'canonical question' that I'd be tempted to reopen. Though I'd yield to a mod's review.

Comment: @David Thomas: Unfortunately, tag wikis still suck. This is why even the book question remains a question today.

Comment: @ruakh yet see this obviously much-loved community wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list - most of the content in in the question, with answers adding on additional information. That's the idea here.

Comment: @ruakh I rolled it back to fit the format of the PHP question that's linked - which, i may note, has not been closed or changed in format. It's much simpler to compile a list of common questions in a community wiki format than ask a very broad set of questions (as you edited it) and have to browse dozens of answers trying to find the one you want. I'll go with community on this one, but so far, it seems people generally like it the way it is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8488/discussion-between-thomas-shields-and-ruakh)

Comment: I moved the list into the answers on @ruakh's suggestion to keep the Q/A mindset of SO.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

See the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

### Basic keywords and general expressions

#### `this` keyword:

- [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1529630)

#### `var x = function()` vs. `function x()`  —  Function declaration syntax

- [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

#### `(function(){`…`})()`  —  IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

- [What is the purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592396/1048572), [How is it called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228281/1048572)
- [Why does `(function(){…})();` work but `function(){…}();` doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1634268/1048572)
- [`(function(){…})();` vs `(function(){…}());`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3384504/1048572)
- [shorter alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5827290/1048572):

  - `!function(){…}();` - [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3755606/1048572)
  - `+function(){…}();` - [JavaScript plus sign in front of function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13341698/1048572)
  - [!function(){ }() vs (function(){ })()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8305915/1048572), [`!` vs leading semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24067605/1048572)
- [`(function(window, undefined){…}(window));`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2716069/1048572)

#### `someFunction()()`  —  Functions which return other functions

- [Two sets of parentheses after function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234491/two-sets-of-parentheses-after-function-call)

#### `=>`  —  Equal sign, greater than: arrow function expression syntax

- [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-in-javascript)

#### `|>`  —  Pipe, greater than: Pipeline operator

- [What does the "|>" operator do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143363/what-does-the-operator-do-in-javascript)

#### `function*`, `yield`, `yield*`  —  Star after `function` or `yield`: generator functions

- [What is "function*" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9620586/1529630)
- [What's the yield keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2282140/1529630)
- [Delegated yield (yield star, yield *) in generator functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17491779/1529630)

#### `[`…`]`, `[ value ]`, `Array()`  —  Square brackets: array notation

- [What’s the difference between "Array()" and "[]" while declaring a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar)
- [What is array literal notation in javascript and when should you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094723/what-is-array-literal-notation-in-javascript-and-when-should-you-use-it)

If the square brackets appear on the left side of an assignment (`[a] = ...`), or inside a function's parameters, it's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

- [Where can I get info on the object parameter syntax for JavaScript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804982/where-can-i-get-info-on-the-object-parameter-syntax-for-javascript-functions)

#### `{`…`}`, `{ key: value }`, `{ [key]: value }`  —  Curly brackets: object literal syntax (not to be confused with blocks)

- [What do curly braces in JavaScript mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699064/what-do-curly-braces-in-javascript-mean)
- [Javascript object literal: what exactly is {a, b, c}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414766/javascript-or-json-what-exactly-is-a-b-c)
- [What do square brackets around a property name in an object literal mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831262/what-do-square-brackets-around-a-property-name-in-an-object-literal-mean)
- [How does this object method definition work without the "function" keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404617/how-does-this-object-method-definition-work-without-the-function-keyword) (ES2015 Method definitions)

If the curly brackets appear on the left side of an assignment (`{ a } = ...`) or inside a function's parameters, it's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

#### `` ` ``…`${`…`}`…`` ` ``  —  Backticks, dollar sign with curly brackets: template literals

- [What does this `` `…${…}…` `` code from the node docs mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36107981/1048572)
- [Usage of the backtick character (`) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/usage-of-the-backtick-character-in-javascript)
- [What is the purpose of template literals (backticks) following a function in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53507972/what-is-the-purpose-of-template-literals-backticks-following-a-variable-defini)

#### `/`…`/`  —  Slashes: regular expression literals

- [Meaning of javascript text between two slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345748/meaning-of-javascript-text-between-two-slashes)

#### `$`  —  Dollar sign in regex replace patterns: `$$`, `$&`, `` $` ``, `$'`, `$n`

- [JavaScript replace() method dollar signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866071/javascript-replace-method-dollar-signs)

#### `()`  —  Parentheses: grouping operator

- [MDN: Grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping)

---

### Property-related expressions

#### `obj.prop`, `obj[prop]`, `obj["prop"]`  —  Square brackets or dot: property accessors

- [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406)

#### `?.`, `?.[]`, `?.()`  —  Question mark, dot: optional chaining operator

- [Question mark after parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63722601)
- [Null-safe property access (and conditional assignment) in ES6/2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015)
- [Optional Chaining in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183944/optional-chaining-in-javascript)
- [Is there a null-coalescing (Elvis) operator or safe navigation operator in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613952/is-there-a-null-coalescing-elvis-operator-or-safe-navigation-operator-in-javas)
- [Is there a "null coalescing" operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript)

#### `::`  —  Double colon: bind operator

- [JavaScript double colon (bind operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31220078/1529630)

#### `new` operator

- [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646698/1529630)
- [What is "new.target"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32450516/1529630)

#### `...iter`  —  Three dots: spread syntax; rest parameters

- `(...rest) => {}`  —  [What is the meaning of “…args” (three dots) in a function definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42184674)
- `fn(...args)`  —  [What is the meaning of “foo(…arg)” (three dots in a function call)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42118201)
- `[...iter]`  —  [javascript es6 array feature […data, 0] “spread operator”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33890525)
- `{...props}`  —  [Javascript Property with three dots (…)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48464211), [What does the '…rest' stand for in this object destructuring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47689680)

---

### Increment and decrement

#### `++`, `--`  —  Double plus or minus: pre- / post-increment / -decrement operators

- [`++someVariable` vs `someVariable++` in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3469885/1048572)

---

### Unary and binary (arithmetic, logical, bitwise) operators

#### `delete` operator

- [What is the purpose of the delete operator in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8945276/1529630)

#### `void` operator

- [What does `void 0` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7452341/1048572)

#### `+`, `-`  —  Plus and minus: addition or concatenation, and subtraction operators; unary sign operators

- [What does = +_ mean in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15129137/1048572), [Single plus operator in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14470973/1048572)
- [What's the significant use of unary plus and minus operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5450076/1048572)
- [Why is [1,2] + [3,4] = "1,23,4" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124884/why-is-1-2-3-4-1-23-4-in-javascript)
- [Why does JavaScript handle the plus and minus operators between strings and numbers differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383788/1048572)

#### `|`, `&`, `^`, `~`  —  Single pipe, ampersand, circumflex, tilde: [bitwise OR, AND, XOR, & NOT operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_logical_operators)

- [What do these JavaScript bitwise operators do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535328/what-do-these-operators-do)
- [How to: The ~ operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260475/1048572)
- [Is there a & logical operator in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3374811/1048572)
- [What does the "|" (single pipe) do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6194950/1048572)
- [What does the operator |= do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12854644/1048572)
- [What does the ^ (caret) symbol do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3618340/1048572)
- [Using bitwise OR 0 to floor a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487977/using-bitwise-or-0-to-floor-a-number), [How does x|0 floor the number in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049677/how-does-x0-floor-the-number-in-javascript)
- [Why does `~1` equal `-2`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31377474/1048572)
- [What does ~~ ("double tilde") do in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4055633/1048572)
- [How does !!~ (not not tilde/bang bang tilde) alter the result of a 'contains/included' Array method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9316612/1048572) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12299665/1048572) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10582286/1048572))

#### `%`  —  Percent sign: remainder operator

- [What does % do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900652/what-does-do-in-javascript)

#### `&&`, `||`, `!`  —  Double ampersand, double pipe, exclamation point: logical operators

- [Logical operators in JavaScript — how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535647/logical-operators-in-javascript-how-do-you-use-them)
- [Logical operator || in javascript, 0 stands for Boolean false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579262/logical-operator-in-javascript-0-stands-for-boolean-false)
- [What does "var FOO = FOO || {}" (assign a variable or an empty object to that variable) mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439579/what-does-var-foo-foo-mean-in-javascript), [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100758/1048572), [What does the construct x = x || y mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2802055/1048572)
- [Javascript AND operator within assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3163407/1048572)
- [What is "x && foo()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6970346/1048572) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12664230/1048572) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6829736/1048572))
- [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)
- [What is an exclamation point in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012003/what-is-an-exclamation-point-in-javascript)

#### `??`  —  Double question mark: nullish-coalescing operator

- [How is the nullish coalescing operator (??) different from the logical OR operator (||) in ECMAScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65022531/4642212)
- [Is there a null-coalescing (Elvis) operator or safe navigation operator in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613952/is-there-a-null-coalescing-elvis-operator-or-safe-navigation-operator-in-javas)
- [Is there a "null coalescing" operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript)

#### `**`  —  Double star: power operator (exponentiation)

- `x ** 2` is equivalent to `Math.pow(x, 2)`
- [Is the double asterisk ** a valid JavaScript operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284569/is-the-double-asterisk-a-valid-javascript-operator)
- [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation)

---

### Equality operators

#### `==`, `===`  —  Equal signs: equality operators

- [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)
- [How does JS type coercion work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523765/how-does-js-type-coercion-work)
- [In Javascript, <int-value> == "<int-value>" evaluates to true. Why is it so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664886/in-javascript-int-value-int-value-evaluates-to-true-why-is-it-so)
- [[] == ![] evaluates to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662231)
- [Why does "undefined equals false" return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277458/why-does-undefined-equals-false-return-false/19277873)
- [Why does !new Boolean(false) equals false in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695341/why-does-new-booleanfalse-equals-false-in-javascript)
- [Javascript 0 == '0'. Explain this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190495/javascript-0-0-explain-this-example)
- [Why false == "false" is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814212/why-false-false-is-false)

#### `!=`, `!==`  —  Exclamation point and equal signs: inequality operators

- [!= vs. !==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889260/javascript-operator)
- [What is the difference between != and !== operators in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889260/javascript-operator)

---

### Bit shift operators

#### `<<`, `>>`, `>>>`  —  Two or three angle brackets: [bit shift operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_shift_operators)

- [What do these JavaScript bitwise operators do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535328/what-do-these-operators-do)
- [Double more-than symbol in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5528119)
- [What is the JavaScript >>> operator and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1822350/1048572)

---

### Conditional operator

#### …`?`…`:`…  —  Question mark and colon: conditional (ternary) operator

- [Question mark and colon in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1771786/1048572)
- [Operator precedence with JavaScript's ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1788917/1048572)
- [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6259982/1106925)

---

### [Assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Assignment_operators)

#### `=`  —  Equal sign: assignment operator

- [What is the difference between the `=` and `==` operators and what is `===`? (Single, double, and triple equals)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/in-javascript-vs/)

This symbol is also used for *default parameters* or *default values* in a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

- [What does (state = {}) => state mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35526463)
- [What does ({"key": "value"} = {}) syntax mean inside a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65523228)

#### `%=`  —  Percent equals: remainder assignment

- [Having Confusion with Modulo operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62771733)

#### `+=`  —  Plus equals: addition assignment operator

- [How does += (plus equal) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826260/how-does-plus-equal-work)

#### [`&&=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment), [`||=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment), [`??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)  —  Double ampersand, pipe, or question mark, followed by equal sign: logical assignments

- [What purpose do &&=, ||= and ??= serve?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64617548)
- [Replace a value if null or undefined in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62824506)
- [Set a variable if undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62824667)
- [Ruby’s `||=` (or equals) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58635332)
- [Original proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-logical-assignment)
- [Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-assignment-operators)

#### `<<=`, `>>=`, `>>>=`, `&=`, `^=`, `|=` — Double less than, double greater than, triple greater than, ampersand, caret, or pipe followed by equal sign: bitwise assignments

- [What do these JavaScript bitwise operators do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4535328)

#### Destructuring

- of function parameters: [Where can I get info on the object parameter syntax for JavaScript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10804982/1048572)
- of arrays: [Multiple assignment in JavaScript? What does `[ a, b, c ] = [ 1, 2, 3 ]` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3986348/1048572)
- of objects/imports: [Javascript object bracket notation ({ Navigation } =) on left side of assign](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26999820/1048572)

---

### Comma operator

#### `,`  —  Comma operator (not to be confused with the comma used in variable declarations)

- [What does the comma operator do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/javascript-syntax-what-comma-means)
- [Comma operator returns first value instead of second in argument list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580596/javascript-comma-operator)
- [When is the comma operator useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579546/comma-operator-where-it-can-really-be-useful)

---

### Control flow

#### `{`…`}`  —  Curly brackets: blocks (not to be confused with object literal syntax)

- [JavaScript curly braces with no function or json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130025/javascript-curly-braces-with-no-function-or-json)

### Declarations

#### `var`, `let`, `const`  —  Declaring variables

- [What is the difference between "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762011/1529630)
- [Are there constants in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130396/1529630)
- [What is the temporal dead zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849/1529630)
- `var a, b;`  —  Comma used in variable declarations (not to be confused with the comma operator): [JavaScript variable definition: Commas vs. Semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3781406/4642212)

---

### Label

#### `label:`  —  Colon: labels

- [What does the JavaScript syntax foo: mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655737)
- [What does ':' (colon) do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799)

---

### Other

#### `123n`  —  `n` after integer: BigInt

- [What does character 'n' after numeric literal mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59977095)

#### `#`  —  Hash (number sign): Private methods or private fields

- [What does the `#` symbol do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64968964/4642212)

### `_`  —  Underscore: separator in numeric literals

- [Javascript numeric separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58965960)
- [Is there a Javascript equivalent to the Ruby syntax using underscores (e.g. 10_000 = 10000) to make larger integers human readable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20350106)

Comment: what is it? ```object!.someKey```

Comment: @AlexeyNikonov I don't think that there is the `object!.somKey` syntax in JavaScript, but in most languages it indicates that you are force-unwrapping a value, saying that you are sure that the object is defined and that it is not optional

Comment: @AlexeyNikonov That's typescript

Comment: @Bergi but what is the name of this operator ? i'd like to google about it more

Comment: @AlexeyNikonov It’s easy to just type the [symbol names into Google](//google.com/search?q=TypeScript+exclamation+point+dot).

Comment: @slebetman They're in the list already